# Drupal upgrading procedure: What are 'core files'?

Tags: drupal

I received an email about new security patch that says I must apply this security patch. But in the instruction there is paragraph that says. 
"Remove all old core files and directories, except for the 'sites' directory and any custom files you added elsewhere". What are 'core files'?

Comment: Core files are basically all drupal files, or the files included when you download drupal.

Comment: I use `drush` to upgrade.  Once you know how to do it, it's easy and it can be automated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal core files are those included when downloading drupal core from its [project page](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal).

At GitHub you can see a [convenient overview](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/tree/7.x).